# BulkCopy with condition in C# for SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy, bcp

I'm trying to copy data from one server to another. The database I'm copying from is very large and updated daily and I'm interested in just copying the previous day.

Using `bcp` I can do this via the `queryout` option. Is it possible to set this when using `SqlBulkCopy`?

Comment: Set *what* using SqlBulkCopy?

Comment: BulkCopy is just using BCP?  Basically, I'd like to add a where clause so it doesn't grab the entire table from the source.

Comment: You can Always copy into a staging table on the first server and that SqlBulkCopy the staging table. However, filtering the input in c# seems more effective

Comment: Or use a view that is limited to the previous day

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to add a `WHERE` clause to `SqlBulkCopy`. But you can filter the rows that you pass to the `WriteToServer` method yourself.

Comment: Where does the filtering happen if you add it to the WriteToServer method?  Are all the rows grabbed and the filtering happens on/after insert?  Or does the filtering happen when grabbing the rows from the src?

Comment: You do the filtering in the app. Maybe you delete rows from a DataTable or you use LINQ to remove rows that the source delivers to you.

Comment: Just so I'm clear - behind the scenes, the actual filtering is happening in my desktop (not on src db server)?

Comment: Yes, the TDS protocol does not have a way to specify a filter for a bulk insert. SQL Server cannot be made to do this. Of course, you are free to push the filter into the source if that is possible. If your source is a query, you can apply the filter there. SqlBulkCopy is just a middle man. It does nothing but sending rows.